# Why is my C code printing out an extra line of rows?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define rows 500 //can define rows as any number

int main()
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<=rows;++i)
    {
        for(j=0;j<(2*i+1);++j)
        {
           printf("* ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So here is my code, what it does is it prints the number of rows set by #define and creates a right angle triangle. But whatever I set that number to it always prints out 1 extra row of stars, and I can't figure out why.

I know I can set it as `i=0;i<500;i++` and just forget about the `#define` statement but I'm trying to make it work with it.

Comment: `for(i=0;i<=rows;++i) != for(i=0;i<500;++i)`. One uses `<=` and the other uses `<`. The former loops 501 times while the latter loops 500 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue with the `#define`, there is one issue with the conditional statement in the `for` loop.

I believe, you'er overlooking the `<=` operator. You need to have only `<` operator. Change

```
 for(i=0;i<=rows;++i)
```

to

```
for(i=0;i<rows;++i)
```

That said, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Comment: oh.. so when it equals 500 it still does that 1 extra loop so it's not less than 500 anymore?

Comment: @thatoneaveeno see, when `i` equals 500, the `i<=rows` still holds TRUE, so it will execute the loop body. Next time, when `i` becomes `502`, `i<=rows` will evalutate to FALSE and the looping will end.

Answer (score 3):

You have made the condition as

```
i=0;i<=rows;++i
```

Probably a typo.It should be

```
i=0;i<rows;++i
```

as 0 to 500 means the loop runs 501 times.

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

```
for(i=0;i<=rows;++i)
```

runs for i=0,1,2,3...,rows

Therefore, it runs  for a total of `rows+1` times.

You can do either of below:

```
for(i=1;i<=rows;++i)   // for 1 to rows
```

or

```
for(i=0;i<rows;++i)     // for 0 to rows-1
```